# How to decrypt undeleted files with encfs

Tags: data-recovery, encfs

I'd like to recover files in encrypted directory by encfs. I put these recovered files in the encrypted directory, but there is no files shown in the mounted and decrypted directory.

Is there any way to see the decrypted file? The recovered files is not same path.

Comment: Just a theory, but it's likely the fuse driver does caching, so it won't notice new files dropped into the mount source. Try remounting.

Comment: Remounting didn't work as well.